# C++ passing pointer to a function error

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I've been having some trouble trying to solve how to save pointer to a function into a variable.

Basically I have a priority queue, which consists of this type of structures:

```
typedef void (*calendar::eventPointer) ();

struct actRecord{
  double actTime;
  int prio;
  eventPointer eventPtr;
};
```

What I want to do is call function `Calendar::CalendarPush()` in `Main.cpp`, pass it arguments `time`, `priority` and a pointer to a method of class (rather object) `Transaction::Event1()`.

But I'm still getting an error:

> a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function

Whole code:

----------MAIN.CPP----------

```
int main() {
    cout << "Inicializuji" << endl;
    double time = 0.0;
    int priority = 0;
    calendar cal;
    transaction tran;

    cout << "Planuji prvni event" << endl;

    cal.calendarPush(time, priority, &transaction::event1);

    return 0;
}
```

----------CALENDAR.H----------

```
class calendar {
    private:
            typedef void (transaction::*eventPointer) ();

            struct actRecord{
                    double actTime;
                    int prio;
                    eventPointer eventPtr;
            };

            std::priority_queue<actRecord> cal;

    public:
            calendar();
            ~calendar();

            bool calendarEmpty();
            void calendarPush(double, int, eventPointer);
            void calendarPop();
            actRecord calendarTop();
};
```

----------CALENDAR.CPP----------

```
bool calendar::calendarEmpty() {
    return cal.empty();
}

void calendar::calendarPush(double time, int priority, eventPointer eve) {

    actRecord record;

    record.actTime = time;
    record.prio = priority;
    record.eventPtr = eve;

    cal.push(record);
}

calendar::actRecord calendar::calendarTop() {

    return cal.top();
}

void calendar::calendarPop() {

    cal.pop();
}
```

----------TRANSACTION.H----------

```
class transaction {

    typedef void (*eventPointer) ();

    struct actRecord{
            double actTime;
            int prio;
            eventPointer eventPtr;
    };

    public:
            void event1();
            void event2();
            void event3();
            void event4();
};
```

----------TRANSACTION.CPP----------

```
void transaction::event1() {

    return;
}

void transaction::event2() {

    return;
}

void transaction::event3() {

    return;
}

void transaction::event4() {

    return;
}
```

Comment: Am I missing basic C++ syntax, or should `typedef void (*calendar::eventPointer) ();` really be `typedef void (calendar::*eventPointer) ();` instead?

Comment: Yes, sure. That was just a mistake. Nevertheless, the problem lasts.

Comment: In other words, the code you posted is not the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: Im sure it is. I'm not sure why Visual studio didn't mark the problem above as an error. I kind of lack expecrience with C++.

The problem is on line:
cal.calendarPush(time, priority, tran.event1);

Where tran.event1 says
"1 IntelliSense: a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function"

Comment: Use one global definition for `eventPointer`, not several mutually-inconsistent local ones. As of now, your intent is totally lost between compilation errors, design problems and inconsistent definitions.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems in your code:

- in `main` you should pass a pointer to a member function like this: `cal.calendarPush(time, priority, &transaction::event1);`
- you define two `eventPointer` types - one in `calendar`, and one in `transaction`. Your method `calendarPush` accepts a pointer to `calendar`'s member not to `transaction`'s member. Make up your mind on this one. For your current code to compile the line in `main` should read: `cal.calendarPush(time, priority, &calendar::calendarPop);` for example, but I'm guessing it's not what you wanted.

If you want to change to transaction:

- make sure `transaction` is defined before `calendar` (like including `transaction.h` in `calendard.h`)
- use this in `calendar`: `typedef void (*transaction::eventPointer) ();`
- look at first point above

And what would be better: try reading about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: Actually this is exactly what I wanted. Now it is possible to call cal.calendarPush(time, priority, &calendar::calendarPop); without an error. But even if I change teh declaration of the type in callendar.h from typedef void (calendar::*eventPointer) (); to 
typedef void (transaction::*eventPointer) (); it still throws an error of "1 IntelliSense: argument of type "void (transaction::*)()" is incompatible with parameter of type calendar::eventPointer". Which does not make any sense to me as it acts like I didnt really change it.

Comment: @JanCoreey I don't follow. If this is what you wanted why do you change it now? And if you want to change it make sure to: 1) include `transaction` before defining `calendar` 2) change both header and cpp.

Comment: The thing im missing is, I want the pointer to point the method of class transaction, not calendar. So what I did was changing the declaration of the function pointer itself in class calendar to point the method of transaction, not the calendar. But it does not seem to work as I expected. What I need to call in main is not the cal.calendarPush(time, priority, &calendar::calendarPop); but cal.calendarPush(time, priority, &transaction::event1); Im really sorry for confusing comments Ive been stuck for so long. Next time I won't work on a project in language I have never worker with before.

Comment: @JanCoreey I've updated the answer. "it does not seem to work" is a bit vague - is there any particular error you're getting?

Comment: The error im getting is "argument of type "void (transaction::*)()" is incompatible with parameter of type "calendar::eventPointer". But that's exactly what does not make any sense to me. I will update the source code above to correspond.

Comment: @JanCoreey You shouldn't have done that, as now your question doesn't make sense. The error is likely off with your sources, try rebuilding and make sure that all the files are being compiled.